# Dynamic Js text boxes - MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created dynamic text boxes that can be added or removed by the user and I want to send whatever the user has input straight to the database. At the minute, it only seems to be sending whatever is in the first text box and ignoring the rest.

What I need is - for each brand name that is entered, send brandName, brandCategory, brandKeyword into the database as a new row.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

```
<form id="manage_brands" action="add_brands.php" method="post">
    <form role="form" method="post">
    <h2>Add Brand Information</h2>
        <p class="text-box">
            <label for="box1">Brand Name:<span class="box-number">1</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="textbox" name="brandName[]" value="" id="brandName" />
            <a class="add-box" href="#"><img id="icon2" src="images/plus.png"></a>
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="bCategory">Brand Category:</label>
        <select class="textbox" id="bCategory" name="brandCategory">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="Arts and Entertainment">Arts and Entertainment</option>
            <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Careers">Careers</option>
            <option value="Education">Education</option>
            <option value="Family and Parenting">Family and Parenting</option>
            <option value="Health and Fitness">Health and Fitness</option>
            <option value="Food and Drink">Food and Drink</option>
            <option value="Hobbies and Interests">Hobbies and Interests</option>
            <option value="Home and Garden">Home and Garden</option>
            <option value="Law, Government and Politics">Law, Government and Politics</option>
            <option value="News">News</option>
            <option value="Personal Finance">Personal Finance</option>
            <option value="Pets">Pets</option>
            <option value="Society">Society</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
            <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
            <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
            <option value="Style and Fashion">Style and Fashion</option>
            <option value="Technology and Computing">Technology and Computing</option>
            <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
            <option value="Real Estate">Real Estate</option>
            <option value="Religion and Spirituality">Religion and Spirituality</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="brandKeyword">Brand Keyword:</label>
        <textarea class="FormElement" name="brandKeyword" id="brandKeyword" placeholder="Add relevant keywords"></textarea>
        </p>
        <br />
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Store Brand" onclick="return confirm('Do you wish to add a new brand?');"/>
    &nbsp
    <a href="home.php" class="link">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if (empty($errors)) {
        // Perform Create
        $brandName = mysql_prep($_POST["brandName[]"]);
        $brandCategory = mysql_prep($_POST["brandCategory"]);
        $brandKeyword = mysql_prep($_POST["brandKeyword"]);
        $addedBy = mysql_prep($_SESSION['username']);

        $keyword = array($brandKeyword);
        $count = count($keyword);
        //implode - the array to join to a string
        //comma is the glue string between each string/displays contents of an array as a string using defined parameter ","
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                $brandKeyword = implode(',', $keyword);

            }
            $query = "INSERT INTO brands (";
            $query .= "  brandName, brandCategory, brandKeyword, addedBy ";
            $query .= ") VALUES (";
            $query .= "  '{$brandName}', '{$brandCategory}', '{$brandKeyword}', '{$addedBy}' ";
            $query .= ")";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            if ($result) {
                // Success
                $_SESSION["message"] = "Brand has been stored";
                redirect_to("add_brands.php");
            } else {
                // Failure
                $_SESSION["message"] = "Information could not be stored";
            }
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#manage_brands .add-box').click(function(){
        var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
        var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Brand Keyword <span class="box-number">' +
        '' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" class="textbox" name="brandName[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" />' +
        ' <a href="#" class="remove-box"><img id="icon2" src="images/minus.png"></a></p>');
        box_html.hide();
        $('#manage_brands p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });

$('#manage_brands').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
    $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#ffffff' );
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $('.box-number').each(function(index){
            $(this).text( index + 1 );
        });
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: `name="yourInputName[]"` - PHP will receive an array.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Absol I've tried that and it still doesn't seem to work, I've changed it in the JS, PHP and HTML.

Comment: You have a textarea in the HTML with the name "brandKeyword" and the text boxes you create in your Javascript are also named "brandKeyword". PHP will only get one of those. What's the "brandKeyword" textarea for, if the user can add text boxes for keywords anyway?


---- You just edited your post and changed the Javascript text boxes to use "brandName" instead of "brandKeyword", but again, you already have a text box in your HTML that has "brandName" and all new text boxes created will also have the same name.

Comment: @BlahArgh  I saw that, I've changed it, still not working though.

Comment: @Kate I don't know if you saw the update I did on my previous comment in regards to your reply. You replied so soon that I figure I should just update my original comment. I probably should have just created another one. Sorry about that, I'm still not fully sure how they're handled in this site.

Comment: Looking at your recent update: You won't be able to do  $brandName=mysql_prep($_POST["brandName[]"]). If setting the HTML tag name to "brandName[]", $_POST["brandName"] is an array. You can access each element using $_POST["brandName"][0], $_POST["brandName"][1], etc., depending on how many exists.